# Specify custom output file path for browserify

Tags: javascript, sdk, browserify

Using CLI , set value to `-o` to specify the output filepath( bundle)

```
node node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd src/index -o lib/bundle.js
```

In the above example , the output file path is `./lib/bundle.js`.

However, I don't want to use CLI , i want to use JS SDK :

```
    const browserify = require('browserify');

    const b = browserify();
    b.add('./src/index.js');
    b.bundle(/* Where to specify the output filepath, is it here */)
     .pipe(/* or here*/)
```

My head will break because of this library. Frankly, webpack documentation is better.

Any help is appreciative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `pipe` to a standard file stream

```
const browserify = require('browserify');
const fs = require('fs');

browserify()
    .add('./src/index.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./lib/bundle.js'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using the [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) build system, you can also do it like this.

(Much thanks to Dan Tello for his [article](https://www.viget.com/articles/gulp-browserify-starter-faq) that helped me get this going in my own environment!).

This approach utilizes the help of another Node module called [vinyl-source-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream).  By using this helper module, you're not dependent upon the deprecated [gulp-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify) package - you can use the latest vanilla [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) package as-is.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// add in browserify module to bundle the JS
// We can use this directly instead of 'gulp-browserify' with help 
// from 'vinyl-source-stream'
var browserify = require('browserify');

// Add in vinyl-source-stream to help link browserify and gulp streams
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', () => {

    return browserify('./js/main.js') // source to compile
        .bundle()   // compile it...
        .pipe(source('popup.js'))  // pipe to output file
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));  // put output back into ./js/
});
```